# Using $_SESSION between pages that are in different directories

Tags: php, session

I was wondering how I would pass something using a session between pages that are in two separate directories. For example, if I had the following code, what would I need to add to make it work?

Page 1: **directory\directory1\directory2\Page1.php**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['example'] = '123';
```

Page 2: **directory\dir1\dir2\Page2.php**

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['example'];
```

Comment: Running against localhost?  Check your response headers to see where the session_id cookie is being set to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if these pages are served within the same domain.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, I must be making a mistake in my own code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to `session_start()` in each page. Just write that, in a single file and share that file between the pages you want to hold the session in.

So, if you have `page1.php` and `page2.php` and `session.php` You can create session either in page1.php and check it in page two like: `echo var_dump($_SESSION)` and vise-versa

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if session-cookies are properly set. Some problems (e.g. Headers already sent) may cause your session cookie to not be set.

If this is working properly, you may have to change the session cookie parameters via [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

By setting the second parameter (path) to `/`, the session cookie is valid for the root of your website and all subdirectories.

Example

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
```

The same settings can also be set in your php.ini or via `ini_set()`. See [Session configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

**Note:**

I'm not sure if these settings have any effect if `session.autostart` is enabled, in which case the cookie-header may already be sent before the changes are made.